# RecylerView is not refreshing onRefresh in android studio

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, pull-to-refresh

I am trying to update items onRefresh in the recylerview but it is not producing the reuquired list. When I close the app and open it back then it gives the updated items list but it does not update items list through onRefresh method. So basically in order to update the list you have to close and open the app and you can not update it in other way.

```
 swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
               
                myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(), items);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), 
                         RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
                //myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                recyclerView.invalidate();
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
```

I have tried both notifyDataSetChanged() and invalidate() but none of them are working. There is also no error in logcat. How do I change the method to update it onRefresh?

I have the same adapter setting in the onCreateView method

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(), videoFiles);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
}
```

This is whole activity with recylerview

```
public class FilesFragment extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    View view;
    MyAdapter myAdapter;
     //     public static List<Files> items; from adapter class
    public FilesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_files, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.filesRV);
       
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(), items);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
       // recyclerView.invalidate();
        swipeRefreshLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.swipeToRefresh);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
           
                
                // recyclerView.invalidate();
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
               // updateData(items);
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }

            public void updateData(List<Files> items) {
               // items.clear();
                myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(), items);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
                items.addAll(items);
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

      
        if (items!= null && items.size() > 0) {
            myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(), items);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
        }
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: why are you making a completely new adapter inside on refresh ? keep one reference to the adapter, update the content, call notifyDatasetChanged

Comment: exactly @a_local_nobody

Comment: I did that but it still does not update items.

Answer (score 0):

No need to set new adapter every time. Just call notify dataset changed like below:

```
recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And before that please make sure that your items are updated. My wild guess is you are not inserting or updating the items. If its a arraylist please insert or update an item before calling the `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Isn't notifyDataSetChanged() enough to update items as when you open the app again the list updates and if not then how do you update the lists in recylerveiw?

Comment: When you open the app recylerveiw renders all the data which are in the list. Now if you got any new data you have to inform your recylerveiw. How do you do that? You put that new data in your arraylist and tell your recylerveiw that, hey I got a new data, please take it from the list and show by calling notifyDataSetChanged. Otherwise if you call notifyDataSetChanged without putting it in that arraylist, your recyclerview will show only those data which are in the arraylist. You got my point? your recyclerview never know from where to get your new data.

Comment: I got your point and I applied this method to update....                                             public void updateData(List<Files> items) {
               // files.clear();
                myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(), files);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), 
                   RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
                files.addAll(items);
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }    But the result is still not changing.

Answer (score -1):

```
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

add this line to notifiy adapter that the data source has changed
put this in onResume() to make it seamless

also you can try to do following

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(null);
recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(myLayoutManager);
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

what this will do is invalidate the recycler view with new updated data

although there is invalidate method present it tend to not work in certain conditions

```
   public class FilesFragment extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    View view;
    MyAdapter myAdapter;
     //     public static List<Files> items; from adapter class
    public FilesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_files, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.filesRV);
       
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(), items);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
       // recyclerView.invalidate();
        swipeRefreshLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.swipeToRefresh);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
           
                
                // recyclerView.invalidate();
               // myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                updateData(items);
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }

            
        });

      public void updateData(List<Files> items) {
               // items.clear();
                myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(), items);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
                items.addAll(items);
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
               recyclerview.getAdapter.notifydatasetchanged();
            }
       
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: why set null and then set another adapter, same with layout manager ?

Comment: thats just to make sure everything syncs up but thats used only if other solution dont work

Comment: why are you creating a completely new adapter inside onRefresh ?

Comment: Thanks for the solution but it is still behaving in the same way.

Comment: did you try changing the flag setRefreshing to true

Comment: It just spins indefinitely

Comment: yup i need to see more of code how you added the addapter. cuz it seems there is issue of multiple adapter are being added

Comment: i would suggest post the whole activity with recycler view

Comment: I have added the whole activity

Comment: okay but why are you creating seperate refrence and new objec of the adapter

Comment: just make a global varible and access it via that